# Aggregated step_count data doesn't match Google Fit app

Tags: javascript, rest, google-fit

I'm developing a web-app which need to receive users Google Fit data. I have 3 step-counters (misfit and miBand trackers+embed phone step-counter). Here my aggregated POST body:

```
 "aggregateBy": [
    {
      "dataTypeName": "com.google.step_count.delta"
    }
  ],
  "endTimeMillis": 1566680400000,
  "startTimeMillis": 1566075600000,
  "bucketByTime": {
    "durationMillis": 86400000
  }
```

My API response data:
4977, 15376, 14511, 8323, 14123, 8250, 5326

My Google Fit app data for the same dates:
4992, 15382, 16155, 13928, 16934, 16691, 6303

As you can see, the values can be almost the same, but also the difference can be really huge for some days. My MiFit app data almost match Google Fit (the second row) data so API response is often wrong.

I tried to replace dataTypeName with `"dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:estimated_steps"` and also with `"dataSourceId": "derived:com.google.step_count.delta:com.google.android.gms:merge_step_deltas"`. Also, different periods. It hasn't helped.

May be anyone faced with the same problem?

PS: It seems like API doesn't count data from miBand sometimes. Also, I found a lot of miBand data in Google Fit Sessions. Is it possible that Google Fit app counts data from the sessions and from aggregated simultaneously?

Comment: Hey, hope u found a solution

The same happens to me, it's like Goggle Fit doesn't retrieve the right number of steps made during an activity. Another thing in common between the users I have reporting this problem is they are all using a band to track their activities, or they are syncing with google using Strava or alikes.

Comment: Actually, I didn't. Seems like it's a general Google Fit issue. Also I started to implement Nutrition stuff and noticed the same problems with data there. But there is no so huge wrong data for Nutrition as for Activity..

Comment: @NicolásCastellanos sorry it was a comment for you )